# Disable trigger inside time interval according to timestamp after Submit

Tags: php, mysql

I have an interesting problem here that someone may be able to help me with. I have a table/form with mostly integers that is occasionally updated every with a batch of new figures. A trigger passes ALL the old numbers to a second table of exactly the same design, as the old figures are important to keep for a certain period of time. The trigger looks like this:

`begin`

```
if NEW.(rowname)<>OLD.(rowname) then
update table2 
set table2.rowname = OLD.rowname
where table2.id = OLD.ID;
end if;
 ...
end
```

This piece of code applies to 100+ of these rows of Integer type. 
Now the people who are entrusted to insert the new numbers, manually, are liable to make mistakes, and going back to the update form to change their mistake will unavoidably pass on the wrong figure to the second table(there are actually 5 tables to keep 5 generations of sets of numbers). So I thought that there might be a way to include a timestamp field in the table and have the trigger be disabled using an initial "IF/THEN" statement that incorporates the timestamp to create a time interval after the SUBMIT in order to make corrections without having the trigger actually trigger. Is this possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible to delay the trigger activation. You need to redesign your process and either enable the users to roll back changes or allowing them to indicate that a change is a corrective one, whereby you update the latest log entry instead of inserting  new one.

Comment: I guess that might mean creating an interval table where they can actually see their numbers(these figures are actually plot points for an AMchart that I designed). When they see the graph they can get a better "view" of the numbers that they punched in. That could work actually. Thanks for the tip(s).

Comment: It is possible to synthesize this with triggers and events working together. I wrote a somewhat similar answer up [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39041181)

Answer (score 0):

I'll look into it out of curiosity @drew, but my conclusion/solution will involve a slight change of semantics in the trigger definition. The rows are 4-digit temps, and the trigger will simply be defined as when ALL new readings are different from the old will the old be passed on to the next table, and so on. The "IF" and "END IF" statements will envelop all the statements referencing all the rows. So that if the old row figure is 2500, the new will simply be inputted as 2501, and the slight offset falls within the margin of error by the instrument that takes the temp reading. This way any changes can take place on the main table, unless of course it is a COMPLETE change, without affecting the archive tables. A practical if inelegant solution, in that it overlooks the complexity and appreciation for the SQL language, which I am not too familiar with to begin with. 
I'm fortunate in that a margin of error is allowed here. Thanks to both of you for your inputs...

The new trigger:

```
begin
if
NEW.row1<>OLD.row1 then
update table2
set table2.row1 = OLD.row1
where table.id = OLD.ID;
and
(if?) NEW.row2<>OLD.row2 then
update table2
set table2.row2 = OLD.row2
where table2.id = OLD.ID;
.....
end if;
end
```

I hope semantically the answer works, if not I'll figure out the details until it does..but you get the idea.

Comment: Final template: begin
if NEW.row1<>OLD.row1 and 
NEW.row2<>OLD.row2
then update table2
set table2.row1 = OLD.row1,
table.row2 = OLD.row2
where table.id = OLD.ID;
end if;
end